# Schedule a single nifi process group for multiple tables in a database

Tags: scheduler, apache-nifi

I have created a process group with following requirements in Nifi :

Fetch data from hive table >> Encrypt content >> upload to azure blob storage .

Now I have 3000 tables for which the above flow needs to be scheduled . Is there any way to use only single flow for all the tables instead of creating 3000 flows for each table .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zkxs.png)

Also I want to execute the azure storage for some of the tables not for all . Is there any way to give instruction in the flow based on any condition that Table 1 should go to only gcloud and not on Azure . Similarly I want Table 2 to go to both azure and gcloud.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that can be done but I hope some optimal approaches are still out there.

**No need for 3000 flows**

`SelectHiveQL` can take an input flowfile which can contain the `SELECT` query so one approach that comes to my mind is you can have the 3000 SELECT queries in a file and use `GetFile` to read that file and use `SplitText` to split it by line and then connect the `splits` relationship to `SelectHiveQL` processor and apply your further processing logic i.e. `EncryptContent` and write to WASB, if needed.

**Decision driven routing**

For your second query which is deciding which files to be put into Azure Blob  and which to be put into GCS Bucket, you can use `RouteOnAttribute` processor.

`SelectHiveQL` writes an attribute `query.input.tables` which contains the list of tables selected in a comma separated format. If you have queried only one table, that table name alone be written for `query.input.tables`. So in `RouteOnAttribute` you can have a dynamic relationship property like :

- `Destination.Azure : ${query.input.tables:in("Table_1", "Table_15")}`
- `Destination.GCS : ${query.input.tables:in("Table_2", "Table_5")}`

Then connect `Destination.Azure` to `PutAzureBlobStorage` processor and `Destination.GCS` to `PutGCSObject`.

In the above example, I have used `in` operator that NiFi Expression Language offers, you can use other operators based on the table naming convention. For example, if you want to have customer tables landed in Azure Blob and Supplier tables landed in GCS, you can use this:

- `Destination.Azure : ${query.input.tables:startsWith("customer")}`
- `Destination.GCS : ${query.input.tables:startsWith("supplier")}`

For a full list of operators and functionalities offered by NifFi Expression Language, take a look at this [document](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont want to schedule all the sql in one go. There are different run schedules for different tables and they might be from different databases as well. Is there any way of maintaining a run schedule table in hive db and then schedule the process group?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward solution for what you have said i.e. Using a Hive Table to maintain run schedule and trigger processors according to that.